# Implement color change using action listener

Tags: java, swing, colors, awt, actionlistener

I have an assignment that calls for a ball to move around the screen based on which button the user clicks and for the ball to alternate between red and green with the click of another button. It all works but the color change. I have a listener and class reacting to the button click but I dont seem to get a change. Is there a better / simpler way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Code I have:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab2b extends JFrame {

Lab2b(){
    setTitle("Lab 2");
    Lab2Panel p = new Lab2Panel();
    add(p);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Lab2b frame = new Lab2b();
    frame.setTitle("Lab 2 - Ball Mover ");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class Lab2Panel extends JPanel{
Lab2Button canvas = new Lab2Button();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

Lab2Panel () {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton leftButton = new JButton("left");
    JButton rightButton = new JButton("right");
    JButton upButton = new JButton("up");
    JButton downButton = new JButton("down");
    JButton colorButton = new JButton("Change Color");

    panel.add(leftButton);
    panel.add(rightButton);
    panel.add(upButton);
    panel.add(downButton);
    panel.add(colorButton);

    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    leftButton.addActionListener(new LeftListener(canvas));
    rightButton.addActionListener(new RightListener(canvas));
    upButton.addActionListener(new UpListener(canvas));
    downButton.addActionListener(new DownListener(canvas));
    colorButton.addActionListener(new ColorChangeListener(canvas));
}


}

class Lab2Button extends JPanel {
int radius = 5;
int x = -1;
int y = -1;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if (x<0 || y<0) {
        x = getWidth() / 2 - radius;
        y = getHeight() / 2 - radius;
    }
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawOval(x,y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);


}

        public void moveLeft(){

            x -= 5;
            this.repaint();
        }

        public void moveRight(){

            x += 5;
            this.repaint();
        }

        public void moveUp(){
            y -= 5;
            this.repaint();
        }

        public void moveDown(){
            y += 5;
            this.repaint();
        }

        public void colorChange(){
            this.repaint();
        }



}

class LeftListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    LeftListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
     this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     canvas.moveLeft();
    }
}

class RightListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    RightListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      canvas.moveRight();
    }
}


class UpListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    UpListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        canvas.moveUp();
    }
}



class DownListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    DownListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     canvas.moveDown();
    }
}

class ColorChangeListener implements ActionListener {
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    ColorChangeListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        canvas.colorChange();
    }
}
```

Button Movement Listener Class Code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 

class Lab2MoveBallListener extends Lab2Button implements ActionListener { 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
        this.moveLeft(); 
    } 
}
```

Okay, changed this code:

```
public void colorChange(){
            this.repaint();
        }
```

To this and it errors on compile with: error: cannot find symbol
            if (g.getColor() = Color.RED){

```
public void colorChange(){

            if (g.getColor() = Color.RED){
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else{
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            }

            this.repaint();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at using a [JColorChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html). It can set the ball color as required. See [How to Use Color Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)

Here you have hard coded the color making it impossible to modify the ball color. Use a class member `Color` variable and assign it from [getColor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html#getColor%28%29).

Aside: Remember to set the color *before* calling `drawOval`:

```
g.setColor(ballColor);
g.drawOval(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call your method `colorChange()` you never say to change a color, you just repaint the screen. You need to change the color somewhere. To do this I'd have a color variable and in if statement within your ActionPerformed method for the Color Button. The if would have boolean that if it's true, set the color variable equal to this color, else set it equal to the other color. Now instead of `g.setColor(Color.RED);` in your `paintComponent()`, you'd have `g.setColor(colorVariable);`. Hope this helps and solves your problem.